# how to display receipts email address in EWS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

In the EWS, I found that in a saved draft EmailMessage m, people could use m.DisplayTo to get receipt's name, but no property to display email address. Then how and where can I get the receipt's email address and ccRecipt's email address, assume that recipt and ccRecipt are not null in the draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ToRecipients and CCRecipients properties. They are collection of EmailAddress instances.